# cx_freeze selenium python 3.6 : No module named 'httplib'

Tags: python, selenium, driver, cx-freeze, httplib

I try to use cx_freeze build python3.6 + selenium to .exe. when I run .exe file  got this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
module.run()
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "tx66.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>
import httplib as http_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'httplib'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 19, in <module>
    import http.client as http_client
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from enum import IntEnum
  File "C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\enum.py", line 2, in <module>
    from types import MappingProxyType, DynamicClassAttribute
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType'
```

In my code, I just import webdriver and used chromedriver not firefox.

Comment: first try installing `httpclient` using `pip install httpclient` and then use `cx_freeze`

Comment: pip shows :Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\lsjws\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-shw_5upr\httpclient\    and I didn't find how to solve it..